# SQL e R - Baixar dados de uma tabela com espaço nos nomes e filtro de integer

Tags: sql, r, postgresql

Tenho um banco de dados no PostgreSQL e gostaria de baixar uma tabela, mas com alguns filtros.

A coluna 'CNAE 2.0 Classe' é uma integer.

```
library(RPostgreSQL) 

PIA_Estab <- dbGetQuery(con,"
                   SELECT *
                   FROM rais.rais_estabelecimento 
                   WHERE 'CNAE 2.0 Classe' BETWEEN 5.000 AND 33.000 
                   ")
```

Entretanto, estou recebendo a seguinte mensagem:

> Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) :    RS-DBI
>   driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERRO:  sintaxe de entrada Ã©
>   invÃ¡lida para tipo numeric: "CNAE 2.0 Classe" LINE 4:
>   WHERE 'CNAE 2.0 Classe' BETWEEN 5.000 AND...
>                                    ^ )
>
> Warning message: In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) : Could not create execute: 
>                      SELECT *
>                      FROM rais.rais_estabelecimento 
>                      WHERE 'CNAE 2.0 Classe' BETWEEN 5.000 AND 33.000

Já tentei utilizar `LIKE` (ex: "5%") e operadores (ex: >=5000)

EDIT:

Coloquei os valores entre ' ' e resolveu o erro.

Entretanto, a tabela está vindo vazia. Se deu deixar `'CNAE 2.0 Classe' >= '5000'` a tabela vem completa, inclusive com valores menores que 5000. O que pode estar acontecendo ?

Comment: Em termos de sintaxe do PostgreSQL um identificador delimitado (ou quoted identifier), como é o campo "CNAE 2.0 Classe" necessita estar entre aspas("). Quando você coloca entre apóstrofos (') você está definindo uma string. Pela segunda mensagem (Could not create execute: SELECT * FROM rais.rais_estabelecimento WHERE 'CNAE 2.0 Classe' BETWEEN 5.000 AND 33.000) me parece que ele está considerando uma string e não um identificador delimitado. Outra coisa é que se o campo é integer não vejo sentido em especificar valores com casas decimais.

Comment: Coloquei os valores entre ```' '``` e resolveu o erro. Entretanto, a tabela está vindo vazia. Se deu deixar  ```'CNAE 2.0 Classe' >= '5000'``` a tabela vem completa, inclusive com valores menores que 5000. O que pode esta acontecendo ?

Comment: Você fez errado. Da maneira como fez está comparando duas strings: a string 'CNAE 2.0 Classe'  e a string  '5000'. Você precisa, obrigatoriamente colocar o nome do campo entre aspas: `"CNAE 2.0 Classe"`.

Comment: @anonimo No R isso ficará a instrução `SELECT` entre ' ' e o nome da coluna entre " ". Ou até pode definir uma string com o `SELECT` assim: `sql <- 'SELECT etc "CNAE 2.0 Classe" BETWEEN 5 AND 33'` seguido de `dbGetQuery(con, sql)`.

Comment: @Rui Barradas: eu não trabalho com R e portanto não poderia afirmar como montar a expressão SQL no R. O que coloquei acima é que a expressão SQL que estava chegando ao PostgreSQL estava errada, de acordo com a segunda mensagem de erro. Creio que seu comentário deve ser endereçado ao Ricardo.

Comment: @anonimo Desculpe, não tinha reparado no seu perfil. Mas, apesar disso, o comentário também chega ao AP.

Comment: @RuiBarradas obrigado ! Agora deu certo ! Inverti as aspas simples com as aspas duplas  e puxou o resultado certo. Obrigado !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inverti as aspas simples `'` com as duplas `"` e deu certo.

```
PIA_Estab <- dbGetQuery(con,'
                   SELECT *
                   FROM rais.rais_estabelecimento 
                   WHERE "CNAE 2.0 Classe" BETWEEN 5000 AND 34000
                   ')
```